# Chrome Mobile Gap between background image and adjacent DIV React

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Im not quite sure how to adress this problem because its solely happening on the mobile chrome browser.

**The Problem:** 
[image]

So as you can see on the image there are gaps around the divs where the background is shining trough. The setup of the code is the following:

```
<div className={classNames(
            scss[timeline-item},
            scss[inProgress]
          )}
          >
            <img
              className={scss.icons}
              src={require(`../../../../assets/images/icons/${icon}.png`)}
              alt={icon}
            />
</div>
```

class of the Div:

```
.timeline-item{
  border: white;
  flex: 1;
  background: url(../../../../assets/images/iconBgSmall.png) repeat-y center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
>
```

(Note here when border is set to 0 then i get the same error in the desktop version of chrome, so i set it to white).

When a step is done an additional class gets rendered into the dom of div:

```
.done {
 background-color: black;
}

.inProgress {
 background-color: green;
}
```

**Image as Background** 
to see the image click on it to open in new window (transparent/white)

[image: Image is here open in new window to see cause of white/transparency]

So as you can see the idea is to use the background color to show the actual state of the timeline. The background image of the div is way bigger than the div itself so it cant be because of the image size.

**Already tried:**

- content: ' ';
- border: 0;
- Removing box shadows (even tough it doesnt have one).
- Negative margins
- outline: 0

Removing all the background colors would work but then my functionality is gone.

**HTML/CSS Snipped**

This is basically the exact code i took and then let it be mapped with mockup data. As you can see here nothing is happening so i dont understand where this error can come from.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EeOZVN

Hope somebody can help!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps outline: 0; helps?

Comment: can you create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please?, although the problem might be `outline`so try reset  it to `0`

Comment: unfortunalty outline: 0 does not change anything.

Comment: please note it is the background which is seen there not a border. it just renders a gap between the image and the adjacent div.